# Ember Inspector doesn't detect ember-cli app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, inspector

I'm running an ember-cli app.  The Inspector (Chrome) says `This webpage is not running Ember.js`.

Looking at the source view on the browser, it includes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">    
...
<script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I get the Inspector to recognize it?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled onto a solution.  I happened to right-click on the page's source-view, and "Inspect" came up, so I chose it.  Inspector now recognizes the page as ember.js.